# $\int_0^\infty(\log x)^2(\mathrm{sech}\,x)^2\mathrm dx$

Tags: improper-integrals, closed-form, hyperbolic-functions

Is there any closed-form representation for the following integral?
$$\int_0^\infty(\log x)^2(\mathrm{sech}\,x)^2\mathrm dx,$$
where $\mathrm{sech}\,x$ is the [hyperbolic secant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicSecant.html), $\mathrm{sech}\,x=\dfrac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}}$.

Comment: I wonder if mathematica 9 gives a closed form for this integral.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal No, _Mathematica_ 9 cannot solve it.

Comment: Nor can Mathematica 12. But interestingly, it can solve $\int_0^\infty(\log x)(\operatorname{sech} x)^2dx.$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Hint:* Use the integral:
$$\int_0^\infty x^n\,\text{sech}^2x\,\mathrm dx=(2^{1-n}-4^{1-n})\,\Gamma(n+1)\,\zeta(n)$$
and take the 2nd derivative with respect to $n$.

Comment: How does one prove this formula?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out thanks to the long hint given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464073/show-that-int-0-infty-xn-textsech2x-mathrm-dx-21-n-41-n-gam

Answer (score 3):

Related technique: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188418/elementary-derivation-of-certian-identites-related-to-the-riemannian-zeta-functi/188437#188437), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290200/int-0-infty-frac-ln-xx2a2-mathrmdx-evaluate-integral/290400#290400), [(III)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189929/what-is-solution-of-these-improper-integrals/189973#189973). Here is a closed form

$$ \int_0^\infty(\log x)^2(\mathrm{sech}\,x)^2\mathrm dx = \int_0^\infty(\log x)^2\left(\frac{2}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}\right)^2\mathrm dx $$

$$= \left( \ln  \left( \pi  \right)  \right) ^{2}- \left( 4\,\ln \left( 2 \right) +2\,\gamma \right) \ln  \left( \pi  \right) +2\,
 \left( \ln  \left( 2 \right) \right) ^{2}+4\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) 
\gamma-2\,\gamma \left( 1 \right) +\frac{1}{4}\,{\pi }^{2}
$$

$$ \sim 1.989349759. $$

**Note:** $\gamma(n)$ are known as [Stieltjes $\gamma$-constants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesConstants.html)

> $$ \gamma(n)= \lim_{m\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{(\ln k)^n}{k}-\frac{(\ln m)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right).$$

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: Yes, it is.