# Find $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^{\pi x}+1}dx$.

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^{\pi x}+1}dx$$

I have closed form $${\pi }^{-n-1}\Gamma  \left( n+1 \right)  \left(1- {2}^{-n} \right) 
\zeta  \left( n+1 \right)$$ but I dont know how to solve the integral step by step

Comment: Tis is 3.411.3 from Gradshtein and Ryzhik. They refer to [Whittaker and Watson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_and_Watson).

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108248/prove-int-01-frac-ln-x-x-1-d-x-sum-1-infty-frac1n2/279065#279065).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $x\mapsto x\pi^{-1}$, to get $$\frac{1}{\pi^{n+1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^{ x}+1}dx$$

Then use that $$   \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{s - 1}}}}{{{e^x} + 1}}dx}  = \left( {1 - {2^{1 - s}}} \right)\Gamma \left( s \right)\zeta \left( s \right) =\eta(s)\Gamma(s) 
$$

For the proof, expand $$\frac{1}{{{e^x} + 1}}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}$$ on $x>0$ using the usual geometric series and integrate term-wise. That is:

$$\frac{{{e^{ - x}}}}{{1 + {e^{ - x}}}} = \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}{e^{ - \left( {n + 1} \right)x}}} $$

Whence $$\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{s - 1}}}}{{1 + {e^x}}}dx}  = \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\int\limits_0^\infty  {{e^{ - \left( {n + 1} \right)x}}{x^{s - 1}}dx} } $$and by $x\mapsto \dfrac{x}{n+1}$, $$\begin{align}
  \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{s - 1}}}}{{1 + {e^x}}}dx}  &= \sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\frac{1}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^s}}}\int\limits_0^\infty  {{e^{ - x}}{x^{s - 1}}dx} }  \cr 
   &= \Gamma \left( s \right)\sum\limits_{n \geqslant 0} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\frac{1}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^s}}}}  \cr 
   &= \Gamma \left( s \right)\sum\limits_{n \geqslant 1} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{n - 1}}\frac{1}{{{n^s}}}}  \cr 
   &= \Gamma \left( s \right)\eta \left( s \right) \end{align} $$

Comment: Very good --- assuming OP is familiar with that other integral.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My bad, Gerry. What about now?

Comment: but how to show that $$   \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{s - 1}}}}{{{e^x} + 1}}dx}  = \left( {1 - {2^{1 - s}}} \right)\Gamma \left( s \right)\zeta \left( s \right) =\eta(s)\Gamma(s) 
$$

Comment: Yeah, how do we show the last relation (elementarily), hmedan.mnsh commented? I think you could have made things far easier.

Comment: @Chris'ssis You're free to provide your own answer. The problem with elementary methods is sometimes they are not strong enough to ensure convergence, unlike DCT, say.

Answer (score 3):

Given integral, $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^{\pi x}+1}dx\\ =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^ne^{-\pi x}}{e^{-\pi x}+1}dx\\ =\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-\pi x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ke^{-k\pi x}dx$$ Now since (by using the definitions of [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and [$\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function))$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-(k+1)\pi x}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-(k+1)\pi x}dx=\pi^{-n-1}\Gamma(n+1)\zeta(n+1)<\infty$$for $n\ge 1$, by [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), we can interchange the summation and integration in the integral to get, $$I=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\int_{0}^{\infty}x^ne^{-(k+1)\pi x}dx=\pi^{-n-1}\Gamma(n+1)\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^{n+1}}$$ The sum is recognized as $$(1-2^{-n})\zeta(n+1)$$ and hence $$I=\pi^{-n-1}\Gamma(n+1)(1-2^{-n})\zeta(n+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

This also can be related to the generalized poly-logarithm function by

$$\tag{1}\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{t^s}{e^{t-r}+1}\, dt=-\Gamma(1+s)\operatorname{Li}_{1+s}(-e^{r})$$

For $r=0$ and by

$$\operatorname{Li}_{s}(-1)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{s}}=-\mu(s)$$

we get

$$\tag{2}\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}+1}\, dt=\Gamma(s)\mu(s)$$

Also by $r=\pi i$ we have

$$\tag{3}\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}-1}\, dt=\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$$