# How to evaluate a certain definite integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{e^{x}+1}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta

How can I show that:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{e^{x}+1}dx=-\frac{\log^{2}(2)}{2}$$

EDIT: This is equivalent to showing that $\eta'(1)=-\ln2\gamma-\dfrac{\ln^2(2)}{2}$.

Comment: You can use Mellin transform techniques. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394219/int-0-infty-log-x2-mathrmsech-x2-mathrm-dx/394243#394243) and follow the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we would like to find $\eta'(1)$ which in essence mean computing $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}\log k}{k}$.

We will present a solution which is in some sense reminscent of one of the proofs of the fact $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=\log 2$. Namely rewriting $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2k}=H_{2n}-H_{n}=(H_{2n}-\log 2n)-(H_n-\log n)+\log 2$ ($H_n$ represents the $n$-th harmonic number) and using the fact $\lim_{n\to \infty}H_n-\log n$ exists (and is in fact equal to Euler-Mascheroni $\gamma$ constant).

First of all we prove that the following sequence is convergent - $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log k}{k}-\frac{\log(n)^2}{2}$ (analog of $H_n-\log n$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants#Representations)). Rewrite $b_n=\frac{\log 2}{2}-\frac{\log^2 3}{2}+\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{\log k}{k}-\int_{3}^{n}\frac{\log x}{x}\mathrm{d}x$ and denote the last two summands as $c_n$ so it is equivalent to prove $c_n$ is convergent. Observe that $\frac{\log x}{x}$ is decreasing for $x\ge 3$. Now $c_{n}-c_{n-1}=\frac{\log n}{n}-\int_{n-1}^n \frac{\log x}{x}\mathrm{d}x\le \frac{\log n}{n}-\frac{\log n}{n}=0$, so the sequence is decreasing. Moreover $c_n=\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{\log k}{k}-\int_{3}^{n}\frac{\log x}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{\log k}{k}-\sum_{k=3}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{\log x}{x}\mathrm{d}x\ge \sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{\log k}{k}-\sum_{k=3}^{n-1}\frac{\log k}{k}=\frac{\log n}{n}\ge 0$,

so the sequence is bounded from below, and it is convergent. (the proof is the same as that of the general fact [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler-Maclaurin_Summation_Formula).)

Now $$a_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\log k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log k}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log 2k}{2k}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log k}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log k}{k}-H_n\log 2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log k}{k}-\frac{\log^2 2n}{2}\right)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log k}{k}-\frac{\log^2 n}{2}\right)-(H_n-\log n)\log 2+\left(-\log n\log2+\frac{\log^2 2n}{2}-\frac{\log^2 n}{2}\right)\to -\gamma \log 2 + \frac{\log^2 2}{2}$$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

In a similar manner the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\log^d n}{n}$$ for integer $d$ (i.e. the $d$-th derivative of eta at $1$) could be evaluated, however the Stieltjes constants (which we referred to earlier) will be present in the answer.

Comment: How did you find this question?

Comment: It appeared in "related" in a question of mine which you might be interested in - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2087446/387821)

Answer (score 12):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over \expo{x} + 1}\,\dd x
=\lim_{\mu\to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{\mu}\expo{-x} \over 1 + \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
$$

> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}
> {x^{\mu}\expo{-x} \over 1 + \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
> &=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> x^{\mu}\expo{-\pars{n + 1}x}\,\dd x
> =\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{n + 1}^{\mu + 1}}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
> {\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over n^{\mu + 1}}
> =-\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}{\rm Li}_{\mu + 1}\pars{-1}
> \\[3mm]&=\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\pars{1 - 2^{-\mu}}\zeta\pars{\mu + 1}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over \expo{x} + 1}\,\dd x}
=\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}
\partiald{\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\pars{1 - 2^{-\mu}}\zeta\pars{\mu + 1}}}{\mu}
\tag{1}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large -\,\half\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}} \approx -0.2402
\end{align}

> See the [Dirichlet Eta Function link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) and the [PolyLogarithm Function Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

## ADDENDA

The limit, in expression $\pars{1}$ has to be handled carefully because $\ds{\zeta\pars{\mu + 1} \sim {1 \over \mu}}$ when $\ds{\mu \sim 0}$. It has the
[Laurent Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Zeta_Function)
$$
\zeta\pars{\mu + 1}={1 \over \mu} + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n!}\,
\gamma_{n}\,\mu^{n}
$$
where $\ds{\gamma_{n}}$'s are the Stieltjes Constants.
Let's consider the limit evaluation. In order to evaluate the limit we just need the expansion, up to order one, of each  factor in
( $\ds{\gamma}$ is the Euler-Mascheroni Constant ):
$$
\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\,{1 - 2^{-\mu} \over \mu}\,\bracks{\mu\zeta\pars{\mu + 1}}\,,
\qquad\left\vert\begin{array}{ccl}
\ \Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} & \sim & 1 - \gamma\mu
\\[2mm]
\ {1 - 2^{-\mu} \over \mu} & \sim & \ln\pars{2} - \half\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}\mu
\\[2mm]
\ \mu\zeta\pars{\mu + 1} & \sim & 1 + \gamma\mu\,,\quad\gamma_{0} = \gamma
\end{array}\right.
$$
From these expression we see that the product
$\ds{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\bracks{\mu\zeta\pars{\mu + 1}} \sim
1 - \gamma^{2}\mu^{2}}$ is already of order $\ds{\mu^{2}}$. We are left with the'middle factor' $\ds{1 - 2^{-\mu} \over \mu}$ such that
\begin{align}&\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}
\partiald{\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\pars{1 - 2^{-\mu}}\zeta\pars{\mu + 1}}}{\mu}
=\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}
\partiald{\bracks{\ln\pars{2} - \ln^{2}\pars{2}\mu/2}}{\mu}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large -\,\half\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please provide more details on that limit at the end?

Comment: It looks like a colorful non-answer to me. The hardest part is to compute the derivative of the product, indeed.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It's true. I left to the OP to complete it. It's somehow pretty long. Maybe tomorrow I'll do it. Thanks.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Fixed. It got some color. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Since for any $\alpha$ such that $\Re(\alpha)>-1$ we have:
$$f(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^\alpha}{e^x+1}\,dx = \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{\alpha}}\right)\Gamma(1+\alpha)\zeta(1+\alpha)\tag{1}$$
by expanding the integrand function as a geometric series, we just need to find the limit of the derivative of the RHS of $(1)$ when $\alpha\to 0^+$. It is worth to consider logarithmic derivatives and exploit the identity $g'(z)=g(z)\cdot\frac{d}{dz}\log g(z)$, since the RHS of $(1)$ is a product and $f(0)=\log 2$. Now we have, in a neighbourhood of zero:
$$ 2^z-1 = z \log2 + \frac{z^2}{2}\log^2 2 + o(z^3),$$
$$ \Gamma(z+1) = 1-\gamma z + O(z^2),$$
$$ \zeta(z+1) = \frac{1}{z}+\gamma+O(z),$$
hence their product is
$$ \log 2 + \frac{z}{2}\log^2 2 + O(z^2)$$
and the value of the logarithmic derivative in zero of $\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{z}}\right)\Gamma(1+z)\zeta(1+z)$ is just $-\frac{\log 2}{2}$.

This gives:

> $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{e^x+1}\,dx = -\frac{\log^2 2}{2}$$

as wanted.

Comment: You wrote: $\zeta(z+1) = \frac{1}{z}+\gamma+O(z)$. I had never seen that before... interesting. I wonder if there is a simple proof.

Comment: Partial summation on the series that define $\zeta(t)$ for $\Re(t)>1$ and the limit $H_n-\log n\to\gamma$ are the only ingredients needed.

Comment: By this way you can compute also $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log^2 x}{e^x+1}\,dx,$$ but its value depends on the Stieltjes constant $\gamma_1$.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\frac{\color\red{\log{x}}}{e^x+1}dx
&=\color\red{\lim_{a \to 1}\frac{d}{da}}\int^\infty_0\frac{\color\red{x^{a-1}}e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}dx\tag1\\
&=\lim_{a \to 1}\frac{d}{da}\sum_{n \ge 0}(-1)^n\int^\infty_0x^{a-1}e^{-(n+1)x}dx\tag2\\
&=\lim_{a \to 1}\sum_{n \ge 0}(-1)^n\frac{d}{da}\frac{\Gamma(a)}{(n+1)^a}\tag3\\
&=\lim_{a \to 1}\sum_{n \ge 0}(-1)^n\frac{\Gamma(a)\psi(a)-\Gamma(a)\log(n+1)}{(n+1)^a}\tag4\\
&=\psi(1)\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}-\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n\log(n+1)}{n+1}\tag5\\
&=-\gamma\log{2}-\left(\frac{1}{2}\log^22-\gamma\log{2}\right)\tag6\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\log^22\\
\end{align}
Explanation 
$(1)$: Divide numerator and denominator by $e^x$ 
$(2)$: Expand the integrand as a geometric series, swap the order of integration and summation 
$(3)$: Recognise the gamma function 
$(4)$: Quotient rule 
$(5)$: Apply the limit and split the sum into two. 
$(6)$: For the first sum, $\psi(1)=-\gamma$, and $\displaystyle\ln(1+1)=\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}1^{n+1}$. I will now show how to evaluate the second sum.
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n\log(n+1)}{n+1}
&=\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\log{n}}{n}\tag7\\
&=\lim_{s \to 1}\frac{d}{ds}\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^s}\\
&=-\eta'(1)\tag8\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\log^22-\gamma\log{2}\tag9\\
\end{align}
$(7)$: Index shift 
$(8),(9)$: See [Dirichlet eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function), [Stieltjes Constants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesConstants.html)

Comment: When I tried to evaluate that integral, I got stuck on the $\eta'(1)$ part. It feels like looking it up is cheating.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I believe this problem can be circumvented by using the laurent series expansion of $\zeta(s)$ about $1$, then use the relation between the zeta and eta functions. The page below may be of some use to you. Though, I concede that looking $\eta'(1)$ up can be considered cheating. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants

Comment: Which, according to Jack D'Aurizio, can be done using some partial fractions (though I have not tried this yet).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
&\int_0^\infty \ln(x)e^{-x}dx = -\gamma\\
&\mathop{\lim}_{s\to 1}\left(\zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1}\right) = \gamma\\
&\Rightarrow\int_0^\infty \ln(x)e^{-sx}dx = \mathop{\lim}_{s\to 1}\left(\frac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty \ln\left(\frac{y}{s}\right)e^{-y}dy\right) \\
&\qquad= -\frac{\gamma+\ln(s)}{s}\\
&\Rightarrow\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{e^x+1}dx = \int_0^\infty \ln(x)e^{-x}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^ne^{-nx}\right)dx = \int_0^\infty \ln(x)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}e^{-nx}\right)dx \\
&\qquad=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\int_0^\infty \ln(x)e^{-nx}dx \\
&\qquad=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{\gamma+\ln(n)}{n}\right) = \gamma\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\ln(n)}{n} \\
&\Rightarrow\Rightarrow \boxed{\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{e^x+1}dx = -\gamma \ln(2) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\ln(n)}{n}} \\
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{n^s} = \left(\frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{4^s} + \frac{1}{6^s} + \ldots\right) - \left(1 + \frac{1}{3^s} + \frac{1}{5^s} + \frac{1}{7^s} + \ldots\right) \\
&\qquad= 2\left(\frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{4^s} + \frac{1}{6^s} + \ldots\right) - \left(1 + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^s} + \frac{1}{4^s} + \ldots\right) \\
&\qquad= 2\frac{1}{2^s}\zeta(s) - \zeta(s) = (2^{1-s}-1)\zeta(s) \\
&\Rightarrow\frac{d}{ds}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{n^s}\right) = -\ln(2) \cdot 2^{1-s}\zeta(s) + (2^{1-s}-1)\zeta(s) \\
&\Rightarrow \boxed{\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\ln(n)}{n^s} = \ln(2)\cdot 2^{1-s}\zeta(s) + (1-2^{1-s})\zeta'(s)} \\
&\zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s-1} = \gamma \Rightarrow \frac{(s-1)\zeta(s)-1}{s-1} = \gamma \\
&\Rightarrow \boxed{\zeta(s)+(s-1)\zeta'(s) = \gamma}\text{ and }\boxed{\zeta(s)(s-1)=1} \\
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\ln(n)}{n^s} = \ln(2) \cdot 2^{1-s}\zeta(s) + (1-2^{1-s})\zeta'(s)\\
&\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\ln(n)}{n} = \mathop{\lim}_{s\to 1}\left(\ln(2)\cdot 2^{1-s}\zeta(s) + (1-2^{1-s})\zeta'(s)\right) \\
&= \mathop{\lim}_{s\to 1}\left(\ln(2) \cdot 2^{1-s}\zeta(s) + \frac{1-2^{1-s}}{s-1}
\qquad-\frac{1-2^{1-s}}{s-1}\zeta(s) \right) \\
&= \gamma \ln(2) + \mathop{\lim}_{s\to 1}\left(\frac{(s-1)\ln(2) \cdot 2^{1-s} - (1-2^{1-s})}{(s-1)^2}\right)\zeta(s)\\
&= \gamma \ln(2) + \mathop{\lim}_{s\to 1}\left(\frac{(s-1)\ln(2) \cdot 2^{1-s} - (1-2^{1-s})}{(s-1)^2}\right) \\
&= \gamma \ln(2) - \frac{1}{2}{\ln^2}(2) \\
&\Rightarrow \boxed{\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\ln(n)}{n} = \gamma \ln(2) - \frac{1}{2}{\ln^2}(2)} \\
&\text{finally}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{e^x+1}dx = -\gamma \ln(2) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \\
&= -\gamma \ln(2) + \gamma \ln(2) - \frac{1}{2}{\ln^2}(2)\\
&\Rightarrow \boxed{\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{e^x+1}dx = -\frac{1}{2}{\ln^2}(2)}
\end{align*}